# autofsldap mounts /home, but not /share

Tags: ldap, automount, autofs

I am pulling my hair out trying to make a client PC mount a /share folder automatically via autofsldap.

Interestingly, mounting the /home directories works perfectly.
The syslog contains no attempts to mounting the /share folder.

This is my automountmap on the LDAP server:

```
# Entry 1: ou=automount,dc=example,dc=com
dn: ou=automount,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: automount

# Entry 2: ou=auto.home,ou=automount,dc=example,dc=com
dn: ou=auto.home,ou=automount,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: automountMap
objectclass: top
ou: auto.home

# Entry 3: cn=/,ou=auto.home,ou=automount,dc=example,dc=com
dn: cn=/,ou=auto.home,ou=automount,dc=example,dc=com
automountinformation: -fstype=nfs,rw,bg,intr,hard,nodev,exec,nosuid,rsize=81
 92,wsize=8192,intr 192.168.1.2:/home/&
cn: /
objectclass: automount
objectclass: top

# Entry 4: ou=auto.master,ou=automount,dc=example,dc=com
dn: ou=auto.master,ou=automount,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: automountMap
objectclass: top
ou: auto.master

# Entry 5: cn=/home,ou=auto.master,ou=automount,dc=example,dc=com
dn: cn=/home,ou=auto.master,ou=automount,dc=example,dc=com
automountinformation: ldap:ou=auto.home,ou=automount,dc=example,dc=com
cn: /home
objectclass: automount
objectclass: top

# Entry 6: cn=/share,ou=auto.master,ou=automount,dc=example,dc=com
dn: cn=/share,ou=auto.master,ou=automount,dc=example,dc=com
automountinformation: -fstype=nfs,rw,bg,intr,hard,nodev,exec,nosuid,rsize=81
 92,wsize=8192,intr 192.168.1.2:/share
cn: /share
objectclass: automount
objectclass: top
```

Any ideas?